# Assembly conflict after upgrading package

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I have a OneClick program, Project A, that references class library project B. Project B had Json.net version 4.5.0.0 that was upgraded to 7.0.0.0. Upon building project A I get the error messages:

`No way to resolve conflict between "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" and "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=4.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed". Choosing "Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" arbitrarily.`

`Consider app.config remapping of assembly "Newtonsoft.Json, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" from Version "4.5.0.0" [C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Blend\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to Version "7.0.0.0" [[projectpath]\Newtonsoft.Json.dll] to solve conflict and get rid of warning.`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1697,5): warning MSB3276: Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent assembly. Please set the "AutoGenerateBindingRedirects" property to true in the project file. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=294190.`

I have cleaned every project in the solution and rebuilt them. I've closed/opened VS, recleaned, rebuilt, same thing. Manually deleted obj + bin folders, same thing.

I've changed the Settings/Publish/Application Files menu to every variation of inclusion/exclusion for json.net.

And finally, I've global searched in Sublime(VS doesn't pick up everything) for 4.5.0.0 and come up with virtually nothing except the json.net references in the manifest files project A creates. I can't seem to find a single lingering reference to the old library, yet it keeps ending up in the manifest upon building.

I've solved my problem by adding `<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>` in the .csproj's relevant `<PropertyGroup>`s, but I'm not sure why it works. Can anyone explain to me what's going on? Is this a bad way to solve this problem?

Comment: Not posting it as an answer as it may not work... but take a look at this.  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/855978/reference-issues-after-upgrade-to-visual-studio-2013-update-2-rc

Comment: That seems to be a result of changing the solution version of .NET, not the specific package.